# Update Redis from v3.2.12 to v6

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I need to upgrade our redis cluster(s) from v3.2.12 to latest (v6). What would be the easiest route for upgrading?

We run Redis as well as Sentinel on each node.

3 node cluster -> 1 master, 2 slaves

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upgrade is pretty standard. i would suggest to upgrade in this order.

1. First upgrade the sentinel nodes which are currently are slaves/replica nodes.
2. After upgrade is completed, it will sync from master node, note that a node can sync from version 3 to version 6 node but not vice-versa.( You can't go back to earlier version)
3. Use sentinel to Failover to upgraded node.
4. Upgrade the old master node.

Comment: Dont we have to change the redis.conf file too? I see `slaveof` in Redis version 3 but in Redis version 6 I see `replicaof`.